# Dynamic class not rendering in browser tailwind - Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, tailwind-css

I am creating a simple functional component with Vue. And I am passing variant as props to the to the functional component so that the component picks up as a class.
My problem is that the class is attached but the color is not rendered in the browser.

```
<script>
export default {
  name: "MyComponent",

  functional: true,

  props: {
    variant: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },

  render(createElement, { children, props, data }) {
    const attrs = {
      staticClass: `bg-${props.variant}`,
    };

    return createElement("div", attrs, children);
  },
};
</script>
```

Below is how I call the component

```
<MyComponent variant="success"> Hello there </MyComponent>
```

**tailwind.config.js**

In here I am using colors from root css variables.

```
module.exports = {
    mode: 'jit',
    purge: ['./index.html', './src/**/*.{vue,js,ts,jsx,tsx}'],
    darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
    theme: {
        extend: {
            colors: {
                primary: "var(--primary-color)",
                secondary: "var(--secondary-color)",
                warning: "var(--warning-color)",
                success: "var(--success-color)",
                danger: "var(--danger-color)",
                info: "var(--info-color)"
            },
       }
   }
}
```

**tailwind.css**

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

:root {
    --primary-color: #1a73e8;
    --secondary-color: #f1f1f1;
    --success-color: #00b74a;
    --warning-color: #ffa900;
    --danger-color: #f93154;
    --info-color: #17a2b8;
    --circle-size: clamp(1.5rem, 5vw, 3rem);
    --spacing: clamp(0.25rem, 2vw, 0.5rem);
}
```

Comment: This is pretty well described in the documentation. Your classes are being purged because you're building them on the fly `bg-{props.variant}` will not render correctly unless you safelist all possible combinations. https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names

Answer (score 0):

@JHeth Thanks for the comment

Although there are many ways of solving the above, I came up with a CSS solution by adding styles to the generated classes in style block.

```
 <script>
    export default {
      name: "MyComponent",
    
      functional: true,
    
      props: {
        variant: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
        },
      },
    
      render(createElement, { children, props, data }) {
        const attrs = {
          staticClass: `bg-demo-${props.variant}`,
        };
    
        return createElement("div", attrs, children);
      },
    };
</script>
<style>
 .bg-demo-success {
    background-color: var(--success-color);
 }
</style>
```

Comment: If this answers the question mark it as an answer.

Comment: You can use safelist as of now in 2022. You might be interested in knowing about it more in my recently added answer !

Answer (score 0):

#### Is it recommended to use `dynamic class` in `tailwind` ?

##### No

Using `dynamic classes` in `tailwind-css` is usually not recommended because `tailwind` uses `tree-shaking` i.e any class that wasn't declared in your source files, won't be generated in the output file.

Hence it is always recommended to use ***full class names***

According to [Docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names)

> If you use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names together, Tailwind will not find them and therefore will not generate the corresponding CSS

#### Isn't there work around ?

##### Yes

As a last resort, Tailwind offers [Safelisting classes](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes).

> Safelisting is a last-resort, and should only be used in situations where it’s impossible to scan certain content for class names. These situations are rare, and you should almost never need this feature.

In your example,you want to have `100 500 700` shades of colors. You can use [regular expressions](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#using-regular-expressions) to include all the colors you want using `pattern` and specify the shades accordingly .

###### Note:  You can force Tailwind to create `variants` as well:

In `tailwind.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './pages/**/*.{html,js}',
    './components/**/*.{html,js}',
  ],
  safelist: [
    {
      pattern: /bg-(red|green|blue|orange)-(100|500|700)/, // You can display all the colors that you need
      variants: ['lg', 'hover', 'focus', 'lg:hover'],      // Optional
    },
  ],
  // ...
}
```