# Why do only a very small subset of tailwind colours render in my app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css

**Problem**

I am displaying some icons in my WebApp. I am styling the icons with tailwind. The colours are user-defined. The user's colour preferences are stored in a MongoDB, which is queried when the page loads. As such, tailwind does not know 'in advance' which colours I am going to need. Due to this, tailwind fails to render the colours correctly (it just shows the colour as white), *unless* the *exact* colour the user chose just so happens to also be literally specified elsewhere in the WebApp (I assume this is because the colour will already be loaded at runtime).

**Question**

How can I tell tailwind to just load the whole colour palette at runtime, in order for it to be ready for whenever a user changes their colour preference to be a previously unseen colour?

**Extra Information**

Below is a screenshot of the app, wherein I am also displaying the 'bgColorClass' which I am supplying as the className. You can see that tailwind is failing to display the bg-red-700 colour. Tailwind is succeeding in displaying the other colours however, as I have deliberately specified them in text in the actual html.

[Screenshot of WebApp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDxTO.png)

Answer (score 4):

[Safelisting classes](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#using-regular-expressions)

Add to `tailwind.config.js`

```
safelist: [
  {
    pattern: /bg-+/,
  },
],
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are using the `dynamic class`. And any class that wasn't declared in your source files, won't be generated in the output file.

### Summary:

Use [Safelisting classes](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#using-regular-expressions) in your `tailwind.config.cs`

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
     ...
  ],
  safelist: [
    {
      pattern: /bg-+/, //   This includes bg of all colors and shades
    },
  ],
  ...
}
```

### Explanation:

#### Is it recommended to use `dynamic class` in `tailwind` ?

##### No

Using `dynamic classes` in `tailwind-css` is usually not recommended because `tailwind` uses `tree-shaking` i.e any class that wasn't declared in your source files, won't be generated in the output file.

Hence it is always recommended to use ***full class names***

According to [Docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names)

> If you use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names together, Tailwind will not find them and therefore will not generate the corresponding CSS

#### Isn't there work around ?

##### Yes

As a last resort, Tailwind offers [Safelisting classes](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes).

> Safelisting is a last-resort, and should only be used in situations where it’s impossible to scan certain content for class names. These situations are rare, and you should almost never need this feature.

In your example,you want to have `100 500 700` shades of colors. You can use [regular expressions](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#using-regular-expressions) to include all the colors you want using `pattern` and specify the shades accordingly .

###### Note:  You can force Tailwind to create `variants` as well:

In `tailwind.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './pages/**/*.{html,js}',
    './components/**/*.{html,js}',
  ],
  safelist: [
    {
      pattern: /bg-(red|green|blue|orange)-(100|500|700)/, // You can display all the colors that you need
      variants: ['lg', 'hover', 'focus', 'lg:hover'],      // Optional
    },
  ],
  // ...
}
```

---

###### EXTRA: How to automate to have all tailwind colors in the `safelist`

```
const tailwindColors = require("./node_modules/tailwindcss/colors")
const colorSafeList = []

// Skip these to avoid a load of deprecated warnings when tailwind starts up
const deprecated = ["lightBlue", "warmGray", "trueGray", "coolGray", "blueGray"]

for (const colorName in tailwindColors) {
  if (deprecated.includes(colorName)) {
    continue
  }

  // Define all of your desired shades
  const shades = [50, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900]

  const pallette = tailwindColors[colorName]

  if (typeof pallette === "object") {
    shades.forEach((shade) => {
      if (shade in pallette) {
       // colorSafeList.push(`text-${colorName}-${shade}`)  <-- You can add different colored text as well 
        colorSafeList.push(`bg-${colorName}-${shade}`)
      }
    })
  }
}

// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  safelist: colorSafeList,                      // <-- add the safelist here
  content: ["{pages,app}/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: tailwindColors,
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

---

Comment: It looks like this post is (mostly) a copy+paste of material that has been replicated in a number of other answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75001383 https://stackoverflow.com/a/75873160 https://stackoverflow.com/a/74957762 https://stackoverflow.com/a/74958043 https://stackoverflow.com/a/74957993. This is not ideal, since improvements to one will not be automatically be replicated to the others, and they will diverge over time.