# Dynamic style rendering tailwindcss

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, create-react-app

I want to render an element with a random color at runtime at every documentstart, using ReactJS and TailwindCSS. However, even though looking at the element through the inspector and seeeing the class properly, it still doesn't work. Here is the code:

```
    const colors = ["red", "orange", "amber", "yellow", "lime", "green", "emerald", "teal", "cyan", "light-blue", "blue", "indigo", "violet", "purple", "fuchsia", "pink", "rose"];
    const [theme, setTheme] = useState("orange");
    useEffect(() => {
        setTheme(colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)]);
    }, []);

    return (
        <span className={`text-${theme}-400`}>test</span>
    );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in Tailwind you can't use dynamic class naming like bg-${color}.

This because when Tailwind compiles its CSS, it looks up over all of your code and checks if a class name matches.

If you want dynamic name classes you should write all the class name.
It expect you to write something like this:

```
<span className={`${true ? 'text-red-400' : 'text-blue-400'}`}>test</span>
```

I know this make the code longer and more verbose but this is the only way in vanilla tailwindcss, you can use some external packages like **clsx** or **xwind**.

Comment: I did this though. `className={\`text-${color}-400\`}`. If this does not work, then how can I make it work with said modules? I want it to have a specific random color every time the page loads.

Comment: You can try to set an object of colorVariants for your span like this:
` 
    const colorVariants  = {
        red: "text-red-600",
        orange: "text-orange-600",
        green: "text-green-600",
        blue: "text-blue-600",
        slate: "text-slate-600",
    };
`
Then in your file, you create a **spanColor** variable that you can manipulate (spanColor = "blue") in your span element:
`<span className={'${colorVariants[spanColor]}`}>test</span>`

Answer (score 1):

**Is it advised to utilise a dynamic class in a tailwind?**

Ans: No

> The usage of dynamic classes in tailwind-css is often not advised since tailwind employs tree-shaking, which means that any class that wasn't specified in your source files won't be created in the output file. It is thus advised to use complete class names

According to Docs

> If you use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names together, Tailwind will not find them and therefore will not generate the corresponding CSS

**Is there work around ?**

Ans: Yes, use **Safelisting** classes in your tailwind.config.cs

> Safelisting is a last-resort, and should only be used in situations where it’s impossible to scan certain content for class names. These situations are rare, and you should almost never need this feature.

Particular to you, you want to have text with different colors. You can use regular expressions to include all the colors you want using pattern and specify the shades accordingly .

---

Note: You can force Tailwind to create variants as well:

In `tailwind.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './pages/**/*.{html,js}',
    './components/**/*.{html,js}',
  ],
  safelist: [
    {
      pattern: /text-(red|green|blue|orange)-(100|500|700)/, // You can display all the colors that you need
    },
  ],
  // ...
}
```

To include all the bg-colors, you can use the following code:

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
     ...
  ],
  safelist: [
    {
      pattern: /text-+/, //   This includes bg of all colors and shades
    },
  ],
  ...
}
```

Comment: to complete his answer, `safelist: [
    {
      pattern: /bg-.+-\d+/, // Matches bg-color-shade classes
    },
    {
      pattern: /border-.+-\d+/, // Matches border-color-shade classes
    },
    {
      pattern: /text-.+-\d+/, // Matches text-color-shade classes
    },
  ],`